# How to programatically check MySql license info?

Tags: mysql

We have a software that requires MySql enterprise edition. Oracle requires that by distributing the software, it must check the connected MySql's license, and not allow user to use the software if it is not enterprise edition.

What is the API for checking MySql license information?

Thanks!

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please feel free to mark it as accepted to give closure to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect to the server and run `select version()` and `show variables like "%version%"`. You can parse the output and take necessary steps if version is not enterprise.

For example, my community edition shows:

```
show variables like "%version%"

Variable_name           Value
innodb_version          5.6.26
protocol_version        10
slave_type_conversions  
version                 5.6.26-log
version_comment         MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os      Win64
```

Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out the current license of the mysql server, you can query the variables like:

```
show variables like '%license%';
```

Of course you must first be connected to the instance like: *mysql -u username -p*